Sets proofing in computability
I have some thoughts about diagonalisation (I hope I use the right term). I've tried taking the sequence of c.e. sets A1,A2,... where Ai is a subset of Ai+1
But I'm stuck what to do next, how to proof that |Ai+1 - Ai| is finite... Would really appreciate your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Probably should just be called "maximal," because "the maximal" implies there isa only one. It seems like you want $\omega\setminus A$ infinite, or you can find a lot of maximal sets.

To construct a maximal set the standard approach is to use the finite injury priority method.

Are you sure you've copied the definition of "maximal" correctly? I think "computable set B" should be "computably enumerable set B."

The definition given in the question is not the standard one. The first part of my answer assumes that's a typo and addresses the existence of a maximal set in the usual sense, that is, a coinfinite c.e. set $A$ such that no coinfinite c.e. set $B$ has $\vert B\setminus A\vert=\infty$. The second part of my answer addresses the OP's question as written, and explains a bit more why I suspect this is a typo.

Standard notion of maximality
This is a difficult result. All proofs use a combination of finite injury and some additional trick; the need for an additional trick (besides "basic" finite injury) is made clear by a very clever result of Lerman/Simpson (Theorem 3.5 of Maximal sets in $\alpha$-recursion theory), building on an earlier result of Sacks (Theorem 10 of Post's problem, admissible ordinals, and regularity), which roughly speaking says the following:

No "uncountable analogue" of computability theory allows maximal c.e. sets to exist.

(For a precise statement see the linked paper; the result stated there is more limited, but in fact their argument gives more than that conclusion - it's extremely robust! See also the introduction of this presentation of mine.) The point is that any proof that maximal sets do exist in the classical setting must use some subtleties particular to classical computability theory. No "coarse diagonalization-style" argument, or even basic finite injury argument, is going to do the job.

Weaker notion of maximality
OK, now let's say we just want to construct a c.e. set $A$ such that no computable $B$ has both $B\setminus A$ and $\omega\setminus B$ infinite. This is vastly easier! In fact, we'll do more: we'll construct a c.e. set $A$ not contained in any coinfinite computable set at all. (This obviates the need for the "$\vert B-A\vert<\infty$" clause, which is why I'm confident that the OP has a typo.)
We have to meet the following requirements for each $e\in\omega$:

$P_e$: If $\Phi_e$ is total and infinitely often outputs $0$, then $\Phi_e^{-1}(\{1\})$ (= the set with characteristic function $\Phi_e$) does not contain $A$.

$N_e$: $\omega\setminus A$ has at least $e$ elements.


Their associated atomic strategies are:

$P_e$: Wait until we see $\Phi_e(x)\downarrow=0$ for some $x$ (which isn't "restrained" by another requirement) and then put that $x$ into $A$. This permanently satisfies $P_e$.

$N_e$: Pick some number $x$ not yet "restrained" by any requirement, and keep $x$ out of $A$.


As usual, we'll allow higher-priority requirements to injure lower-priority ones, with the priority ordering given by $$P_0>N_0>P_1>N_1>P_2>N_2>...$$ The exact priority order used is unimportant as long as (it's computable and) every requirement is only below finitely many requirements. By induction (going "down" the priority order), each requirement is injured only finitely many times and so is eventually satisfied.
Note that this is a completely standard finite-injury argument. By contrast, the finite injury argument used for the construction of a maximal c.e. set in the usual sense is, as noted above, much trickier (and necessarily so). Additionally, it's a good exercise to show that the set $A$ constructed above is not maximal in the usual sense.

OP’s definition of maximal set appears to be weaker than  the usual one; OP only requires maximality with respect to recursive sets, whereas the usual definition requires maximality with respect to all r.e. sets. Do you happen to know if it really is a weaker notion?

@MitchellSpector It's much weaker. Moreover, it's clearly a typo, since otherwise the condition $B-A<\infty$ is unneeded: only in the case where $B$ can be arbitrary c.e. do we need to account for this possibility. There are c.e. sets which are not contained in any coinfinite computable sets, full stop. That said, I'll edit my answer to address this.

@MitchellSpector See my edit.

Thanks for working it out — my gut feeling was that it was much weaker and was likely a typo, but I hadn't really thought about it.

… And that’s a great answer!
